# Custom 'Chatter mention' like functionality in visualforce

Tags: visualforce, javascript, chatter

Is there any salesforce method or a JavaScript based 'chatter mention' like functionality, where a person can type in the name and accordingly it would display matching users instantly as a dropdown list. Sort of similar to chatter, twitter and facebook mention functionalities

Comment: No there isn't. Depending on where you want to use it, you can build it yourself though.

Comment: I want to implement it in a visualforce page. Any rough idea how can I build it ? Would it involve using a JavaScript/jQuery based library.

Comment: Could, but not necesairly, that's a broad question. If you're not sure how to do that or what the options are it may be best to start with learning the basics of Visualforce and Javascript.

Comment: The API to call to get the list of mention completions has a couple of variations. In the Chatter REST API, use: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_resources_mentions_completions.htm. In Apex, use: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_ConnectAPI_Mentions_static_methods.htm#apex_ConnectAPI_Mentions_static_methods (note that the Apex doc is omitting the method name "getMentionCompletions" for some reason).